# Sending httprequest to Heroku node js app gets "connection refused" error at client side

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, httprequest

My node app is up and running (listening). It is in essence a bunch of rest api handlers. 
I am sending http requests from my test java client using general java codes (Apache httprequest and httpclient to execute the simple http commands).

The thing is the java http client side instantly gets an IO exception after send the request to the app. Saying " org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com:38084 refused"

Is there any thing i missed so as to make http calls from a java client?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never supposed to connect to any port other than 80 or 443 when connecting to `foo.herokuapp.com`. Granted, your app listens on some port (given by the `PORT` environment variable), but you still need to connect to port 80 (for http).

You are not connecting directly to your dyno(s), bur rather to a Heroku gateway. Heroku's gateway will do the routing (from the gateway to your application) and port forwarding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using curl to try to replicate the connection problem. If it works correctly with curl (or for that matter, in your browser), than you know you have a Java client issue.